# Derivative of a Function $ln(1+\exp(-y.w^T.\phi_W(x_i) ))$

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, neural-networks, derivative

I want to take derivative of  $ln(1+\exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i) ))$ with respect to $w$. So far what i have done is

Let $u=1+\exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i) )$, The above expression will become $ln(u)$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{1}{u}$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial w} = \exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i)).\frac{\partial(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i))}{\partial w}$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial w} = \exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i)).(-y.\phi_{W}(x_i))$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}.\frac{\partial u}{\partial w}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i) )}.\exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i)).(-y.\phi_{W}(x_i))$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=\frac{\exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i)).(-y.\phi_{W}(x_i))}{1+\exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i) )}.$

But my professor said that the answer is

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=\frac{(-y.\phi_{W}(x_i))}{1+\exp(-y.w^T.\phi_{W}(x_i) )}.$

I dont see any mistake in my calculations!

Comment: Can you also share some context about the question so that we can add a couple of more tags? Was this about neural nets for example? or SVM?

Comment: @gunes this is logistic regression based on neural net feature map!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3727567/14578

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct, and probably your professor said a slightly different version of your answer:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = \frac{-y\phi_W(x_i)}{1+\exp (yw^T\phi_W(x_i))}$$

Comment: i get our point! but how are the equal?

Comment: multiply both num and denom with exp(-..)